# What's the proper place for a site's logo?

Tags: html, validation

Right after my `<body>`, as part of the header I add to each page, is my site's logo. This `<img>` is within an `<a>` tag, pointing to my index page.

Here's what [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

> Line 21, Column 38: document type does not allow element "a" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

(I would past the rest of the message, but the html tags in it get messed up, I don't know how to escape them within a blockquote).

What's the proper place to put an logo? Logically, it's not within a division. Making a blank container element seems rather silly.

Local source:

```
...
<body>
<a title="Home" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"/></a>
....
```

Complete source: http://pastie.org/5998955

Comment: post your HTML so we can see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use XHTML, then you're going to have to wrap inline elements in block elements to validate.

You could use HTML5 to do what you're doing and have it validate (but you'll have to add `alt` attributes to your images).

Pastie: http://pastie.org/5998964

Comment: The requirement on wrapping inline content and elements in block elements applies in Strict version of both XHTML 1.0 and HTML 4.01, and it does not apply in Transitional version of either of them.

Answer (score 2):

That error is error is referring to you placing an inline block element, without a container block.

You'll have to do something like this to get it valid:

```
<body>
<div><a title="Home" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"/></a></div>
```

The error clearly states this, and even suggests what tags you can use to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not "where to put the site's logo", your issue is malformed HTML based on the doctype you have specified in your head section.

A is an inline tag and needs to be wrapped by a block-level tag such as P or DIV.

Comment: What is the point of having a div that doesn't group anything together?